# How can I get the the correct row number for the records in this query

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

All,

I have the following query and it creates a result set as I expect, but the real records all comeback with a row number of 1. I was expecting them to come back with an incrementing row number like the fake records do (when you see the code and results you'll see what I mean.).

```
Declare @FakeEquipment TABLE(
EquipmentID varchar(25),
EquipmentDesc varchar(150), 
TrackingID varchar(25))

Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa01',NULL,'zzz01')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa02',NULL,'zzz01')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa03',NULL,'zzz01')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa04',NULL,'zzz01')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa05',NULL,'zzz01')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa06',NULL,'zzz01')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa07',NULL,'zzz01')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa08',NULL,'zzz01')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa09',NULL,'zzz01')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa10',NULL,'zzz01')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa01',NULL,'zzz02')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa02',NULL,'zzz02')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa03',NULL,'zzz02')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa04',NULL,'zzz02')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa05',NULL,'zzz02')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa06',NULL,'zzz02')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa07',NULL,'zzz02')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa08',NULL,'zzz02')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa09',NULL,'zzz02')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa10',NULL,'zzz02')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa01',NULL,'zzz03')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa02',NULL,'zzz03')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa03',NULL,'zzz03')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa04',NULL,'zzz03')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa05',NULL,'zzz03')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa06',NULL,'zzz03')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa07',NULL,'zzz03')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa08',NULL,'zzz03')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa09',NULL,'zzz03')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa10',NULL,'zzz03')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa01',NULL,'zzz04')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa02',NULL,'zzz04')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa03',NULL,'zzz04')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa04',NULL,'zzz04')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa05',NULL,'zzz04')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa06',NULL,'zzz04')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa07',NULL,'zzz04')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa08',NULL,'zzz04')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa09',NULL,'zzz04')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa10',NULL,'zzz04')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa01',NULL,'zzz05')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa02',NULL,'zzz05')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa03',NULL,'zzz05')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa04',NULL,'zzz05')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa05',NULL,'zzz05')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa06',NULL,'zzz05')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa07',NULL,'zzz05')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa08',NULL,'zzz05')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa09',NULL,'zzz05')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa10',NULL,'zzz05')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa01',NULL,'zzz06')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa02',NULL,'zzz06')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa03',NULL,'zzz06')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa04',NULL,'zzz06')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa05',NULL,'zzz06')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa06',NULL,'zzz06')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa07',NULL,'zzz06')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa08',NULL,'zzz06')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa09',NULL,'zzz06')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa10',NULL,'zzz06')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa01',NULL,'zzz07')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa02',NULL,'zzz07')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa03',NULL,'zzz07')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa04',NULL,'zzz07')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa05',NULL,'zzz07')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa06',NULL,'zzz07')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa07',NULL,'zzz07')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa08',NULL,'zzz07')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa09',NULL,'zzz07')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa10',NULL,'zzz07')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa01',NULL,'zzz08')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa02',NULL,'zzz08')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa03',NULL,'zzz08')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa04',NULL,'zzz08')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa05',NULL,'zzz08')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa06',NULL,'zzz08')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa07',NULL,'zzz08')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa08',NULL,'zzz08')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa09',NULL,'zzz08')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa10',NULL,'zzz08')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa01',NULL,'zzz09')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa02',NULL,'zzz09')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa03',NULL,'zzz09')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa04',NULL,'zzz09')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa05',NULL,'zzz09')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa06',NULL,'zzz09')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa07',NULL,'zzz09')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa08',NULL,'zzz09')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa09',NULL,'zzz09')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa10',NULL,'zzz09')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa01',NULL,'zzz10')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa02',NULL,'zzz10')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa03',NULL,'zzz10')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa04',NULL,'zzz10')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa05',NULL,'zzz10')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa06',NULL,'zzz10')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa07',NULL,'zzz10')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa08',NULL,'zzz10')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa09',NULL,'zzz10')
Insert into @FakeEquipment values( 'aaaa10',NULL,'zzz10')


Select 
        Equipment_EquipmentID,
        Equipment_Description,
        JobAccount_TrackingID
        ,row as rowcnt

        from 
        (
        Select row_number() over (partition by Equipment_EquipmentID order by JobAccount_TrackingID) row,*
        from 

        (SELECT DISTINCT
        CustomizedFieldLogEquipmentJobAccount_1.Equipment_EquipmentID, 
        CustomizedFieldLogEquipmentJobAccount_1.Equipment_Description, 
        CustomizedFieldLogEquipmentJobAccount_1.JobAccount_TrackingID
        FROM
        CustomizedFieldLogEquipmentJobAccount AS CustomizedFieldLogEquipmentJobAccount_1 INNER JOIN CustomizedAccount ON CustomizedFieldLogEquipmentJobAccount_1.Account_AccountID = CustomizedAccount.AccountID
        WHERE
        (CustomizedAccount.AppliesToEquipment = 1)
        AND 
        (CustomizedFieldLogEquipmentJobAccount_1.FieldLog_FieldLogID =1219)
        AND
        IsRented = 0
        AND
        isnumeric(right(CustomizedFieldLogEquipmentJobAccount_1.JobAccount_TrackingID,1))=1

        union

        select 
        EquipmentID, 
        EquipmentDesc,
        TrackingID
        from @FakeEquipment) a 
)b 

Group By
Equipment_EquipmentID,
Equipment_Description,
JobAccount_TrackingID
,row
order by Equipment_EquipmentID
```

It returns results as follows:

```
Equipment_EquipmentID   Equipment_Description   JobAccount_TrackingID   rowcnt
1218    PAVER   0441-01409  1
127 Ford F250 Pick-Up   0441-01409  1
1350    PNEUMATIC ROLLER    0441-01409  1
1354    VIBRATORY PUP ROLLER    0441-01409  1
1445    JOHN DEERE SKIP 0441-01409  1
16-003  FORD F-350  0441-01409  1
30  F550 CREW TRUCK 0441-01409  1
3-007   TRAFFIC CONTROL F-550   0441-01409  1
6-002   CAT PAVING ROLLER   0441-01409  1
6-006   CAT PAVING ROLLER   0441-01409  1
aaaa01  NULL    zzz01   1
aaaa01  NULL    zzz02   2
aaaa01  NULL    zzz03   3
aaaa01  NULL    zzz04   4
aaaa01  NULL    zzz05   5
aaaa01  NULL    zzz06   6
aaaa01  NULL    zzz07   7
aaaa01  NULL    zzz08   8
aaaa01  NULL    zzz09   9
aaaa01  NULL    zzz10   10
```

As you can see the records from the fake equipment table all have the correct row number whereas the real records all have a row number of 1.

What I'm trying to do is split the record set between 2 SSRS 2005 matrix controls so each one has 6 records (for a max of 12) But I'm unable to do that. Any help in this direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is numbering the records as expected. You are partitioning the data by `Equipment_EquipmentID` and the data that you are getting from the first part of the `union` the values are all different. So the `row_number` will not increment.

The `row_number()` will only increment if the values in the partition are the same which your values are not.

If you want to use `row_number()` you might have to alter the way you are partitioning.

For example using the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE yourData
    ([Equipment_EquipmentID] varchar(6), [JobAccount_TrackingID] varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO yourData
    ([Equipment_EquipmentID], [JobAccount_TrackingID])
VALUES
    ('1218', '0441-01409'),
    ('127', '0441-01409'),
    ('1350', '0441-01409'),
    ('1354', '0441-01409'),
    ('1445', '0441-01409'),
    ('16-003', '0441-01409'),
    ('30', '0441-01409'),
    ('3-007', '0441-01409'),
    ('6-002', '0441-01409'),
    ('6-006', '0441-01409')
;
```

If you using the following query:

```
select *,
  row_number() over(partition by Equipment_EquipmentID order by JobAccount_TrackingID) rn1
from yourdata;
```

You will see that the row number is not incrementing.

But if you change the partition to the following:

```
select *,
  row_number() over(partition by JobAccount_TrackingID order by JobAccount_TrackingID) rn2
from yourdata;
```

The row number increments.

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06831/5) of both queries.

Comment: Thank You Bluefeet. That did the trick of getting row numbers correct. But now When I try to filter the Matrix control based on the value of Row count, I get an error that says 'Can't compare data of types System.Int64 and System.String. Please check the data type returned by the filter expression.'

Comment: @CraigBobchin well the row number value will be a int and if you are trying to apply a string value to filter, then you will have to convert that value.

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to use an =6 as the value to check. But now I've hit another strange issue.
The 1st Matrix fills out just fine with the filter set to RowNum < =6. But the 2nd Matrix with a filter of RowNum > =6 (or even >= =7) drops the rows 7 and 8 and shows 9 and 10. It should show all of them. 

If I add to the filter Left(Fields.JobaccttrackingID,1) != z then I get all the rows but now lose the fake columns I need.

GRRRRRR

Answer (score 0):

It will be possible when you actually add unique row ID.

Start by adding a new column to the table for "ID" and automatically populate it with an incremented number.

Then each row will have a unique ID and you can call specific rows by that ID.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for bluefeet's answer. I prefer to let the database do more computation than the report though, in which case outputting a "group" column which decided the matrix, and then having the matrix filter on the "group" column might be simpler:

```
SELECT  *, 
        [Grouping] = CASE 
            WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) <= 6 THEN 'A' 
            WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) <= 12 THEN 'B' 
            ELSE 'C' 
        END 
FROM    ...
```